# Javascript Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'location' has already been declared at script.js:1 (anonymous) @ script.js:1

Tags: javascript

```
var currentLocation = 'Home';



//Locations array

var locations = [];


locations[0] = new location('Home',"You look around and see a single wooden door in front of you, the walls are tiled with broken stone (almost purposefully) YOU CAN TRAVEL: NORTH");

locations[1] = new location('ballRoom','');

locations[2] = new location('artRoom','');

locations[3] = new location('keyRoom','');
//A locked door is at the end of this.

locations[4] = new location('Hall', "You see a quaint hall that gives you an ominous feeling, however you see a door at the opposite end of the hall. YOU CAN TRAVEL: NORTH, SOUTH");

//This is where all the treasure is kept.
locations[5] = new location('Cellar',''); //Can only enter if key is in possesion.

function location(name,description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

function clearForm() {
   document.getElementById('userInput').reset();

}

//Check if user typed North, South,East or West
function checkInput() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('inputBox').value;

    elem.toUpperCase();

    if(elem === 'PLAY') {
        if(currentLocation === location[0].name) {
            var el = document.getElementById('gameText');
            el.innerHTML = location[0].description;
            clearForm();
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to write a Text Adventure in Javascript and I am having some difficulty. When I run this code I get the console error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'location' has already been declared
    at script.js:1
(anonymous) @ script.js:1

I am not sure why this is happening and would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why exactly this is happening. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `if(currentLocation === location[0].name) {...` <- missing an "s" there, it's `locations[0]`

Comment: If you don't name functions and arrays almost the same thing, it's easier to keep track

Comment: Thank you, that worked, and I appreciate the tip!

Comment: Don’t name anything `location`. `window.location` already exists, so don’t override that.

Comment: @Xufox …don't name anything `location` *in the global scope*, to be specific. By wrapping the code in an IIFE it could be made to work.